# Unit testing actix actors, sending messages to different types of actor

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I'm trying to use the Rust Actix actor framework where I have a thread polling some hardware, forming simple event messages and sending them to an Actor via its `Addr`. There's an enum `KeyingEvent` that forms the `Message`.

In my tests, I have an Actor that captures incoming `KeyingEvents`, and records them for the test to verify:

```
    struct CapturingKeyingEventReceiver {
        received_keying_events: Vec<KeyingEvent>,
    }
    impl CapturingKeyingEventReceiver {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                received_keying_events: vec![],
            }
        }
    }
    impl Actor for CapturingKeyingEventReceiver {
        type Context = Context<Self>;
    }
    impl Handler<KeyingEvent> for CapturingKeyingEventReceiver {
        type Result = ();
        fn handle(&mut self, keying_event: KeyingEvent, _ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
            info!("Keying Event {}", keying_event);
            self.received_keying_events.push(keying_event);
        }
    }
```

I start this and get its Addr with:

```
let capturing_keying_event_receiver = CapturingKeyingEventReceiver::new().start();
```

This is an Addr, and I could pass this to my threaded code's constructor....

However in my application code, I have a different Actor, `KeyingEventRouter` that also handles these messages and routes them to various other subsystems:

```
struct KeyingEventRouter {
...
}
impl Actor for KeyingEventRouter {
...
}
impl Handler<KeyingEvent> for KeyingEventRouter {
...
}
```

The problem I have is in my threaded code constructor, how can I pass a generic `Addr<???>` as the destination actor to which the thread should send messages? - I've tried specifying the parameter in the constructor as:

```
pub fn new(keying_event_receiver: Addr<dyn Actor>) -> Self {
...
```

But Rust disallows this:

```
help: specify the associated type: `Actor<Context = Type>`
```

I'd like it to be able to send these messages to any actor that is a `Handler<KeyingEvent>`. How do I allow the constructor to take an `Addr<CapturingKeyingEventReceiver>` in my test, and an `Addr<KeyingEventRouter>` in my application code?

In Java (handwaving a bit) I'd create an interface `KeyingEventReceiver`, have `CapturingKeyingEventReceiver` and `KeyingEventRouter` inherit from it, and pass an `Addr<KeyingEventReceiver>`..... but how do you say 'impl Actor from KeyingEventReceiver' since `KeyingEventReceiver` has to be a concrete struct?

Comment: I'd still be interested in a solution to this, to further my understanding of design/limitations using Rust.

I found a way to achieve what I was thinking with my handwavy Java approach - If you have an `Actor<CapturingKeyingEventReceiver>`, you can obtain its `Addr<CapturingKeyingEventReceiver>`, and from this, call the `recipient()` function. This gives you a `Recipient<KeyingEvent>` which will be the same type in my test and production code.

I haven't been able to get my code working with Actix, even with the above; documentation is very sparse, so am trying Riker.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Recipient](https://docs.rs/actix/0.12.0/actix/struct.Recipient.html)

You would need to do:

```
let addr = CapturingKeyingEventReceiver::new().start();

/// https://docs.rs/actix/0.12.0/src/actix/address/mod.rs.html#142-150
let keying_event_receiver = addr.recipient();

pub fn new(keying_event_receiver: Recipient<KeyingEvent>) -> Self {
    keying_event_receiver.send(...)
```

You can also see these tests on the actix crate: https://docs.rs/actix/0.12.0/src/actix/address/mod.rs.html#401

Comment: Thank you, Njuguna. This would work; I'll use this approach if I revisit Actix in other projects. I've since changed the architecture to use the bus crate, and careful sharing of data between the various threaded objects in my system - I believe the tight encapsulation of state in Actix actors would not work well, in my case.